# Shading every other vertical month, alternating white and gray

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have boxplots of data with one set of boxplots for each month. But together, they get busy and it isn't clear which box goes with which date. Is there a way to shade every other vertical month light gray so I can easily see which ones go with which month?

Edit: I'm already using geom_polygon for another part of the plot that I commented out for now.

```
date <- seq(as.Date('2015-09-15'), as.Date('2016-09-30'), by = "2 days")
x <- rnorm(length(date))
date <- date[order(x)]

Date <- format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m")
values <- rnorm(length(x),.16,.01)
type <- c(rep("a",63),rep("b",64),rep("c",64))
new.table <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(Date,type))

dataset <- data.frame(values,date,type,Date)

if(length(which(levels(factor(type))=="c"))==0){
  count.data <- rep(0,length(levels(factor(Date))))
}else{count.data <- new.table[,names(new.table)=="c"]}

ly <- length(count.data)

max.count <- max(count.data)
max.right <- max.count*4
max.box <- max(dataset$values,na.rm=T)
min.box <- 5/4*min(dataset$values,na.rm=T)-max.box/4
box.25 <- (max.box-min.box)/4

x <- c(0:(ly+1),c((ly+1):0))
y <- c(0,count.data,rep(0,(ly+3)))*(box.25/max.count)+min.box
poly.data <- data.frame(x,y)

dates1 <- levels(factor(dataset$Date))
noB <- length(dates1)

new.table$Date <- rownames(new.table)


library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(dataset,aes(x=Date,y=values,fill=type))+
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width = 0.7))+
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar",width=0.7)+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min.box,max.box))+
  #geom_polygon(data=poly.data,mapping = aes(x=x,y=y),fill="grey30")+
  #scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.-min.box)*max.count/box.25, name = "Sec axis"),breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10))+
  labs(title="Boxplot of values Over Time",y="values",x="Date (year-month)")+
  theme_classic(base_size=15)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = ifelse(noB>15,45,0), hjust=ifelse(noB>15,1,0.5)),panel.grid.major=element_line("light grey"))
p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `geom_rect` with a separate data.frame (here: `shades`)

```r
shades <- data.frame(xmin=seq(1.5,length(unique(dataset$Date))-1.5, 2),
                     xmax=seq(2.5,length(unique(dataset$Date))+.5, 2),
                     ymin=0, ymax=Inf)

ggplot(dataset,aes(x=Date,y=values,fill=type))+
    geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width = 0.7))+
    stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar",width=0.7)+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min.box,max.box))+
    #geom_polygon(data=poly.data,mapping = aes(x=x,y=y),fill="grey30")+
    #scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.-min.box)*max.count/box.25, name = "Sec axis"),breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10))+
    labs(title="Boxplot of values Over Time",y="values",x="Date (year-month)")+
    theme_classic(base_size=15)+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = ifelse(noB>15,45,0), hjust=ifelse(noB>15,1,0.5)),panel.grid.major=element_line("light grey")) +
    geom_rect(inherit.aes = F, data = shades, mapping = aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I just made a minor change to allow for differing numbers of dates (with an even number, the "shades" part doesn't work.

Comment: What about removing just the vertical lines within the plot, but not the x-axis tick marks? Is that possible? I tried the "scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL)" but that didn't work.

Comment: To remove the vertical lines, use `panel.grid.major.y` instead of `panel.grid.major` in your code.

Comment: The `shades` part basically maps a  rectangle around every other boxplot group. Not sure what you are displaying now, but you should be able to adjust the positions based on how many ticks on the date axis you have (Date is categorial in `dataset`).

Comment: The 'shades' part outputs differ in length for xmin and xmax is the length of unique dates is an even number, which results in an error. So I used a ceiling function to fix that. So if there is an even number of dates, then the final column in the plot will be gray, otherwise, it will be white. That panel grid recommendation worked as well.